# How to get value of textviews on button click from a listview?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

i have a listview with a custom adapter class . Each of the list items contain 2 **text view** and one **Button** . i want to get the data of those **text views** while i click on the **Button** inside the list .

**below is the demo model of listview**

[image: ]]

please help me out guys

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    IconView icon;
    TextView title;
    TextView description;
    Button favour;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(textViewResourceId, parent, false);
    }

    icon = (IconView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.station_icon);
    title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.station_title);
    description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.station_description);
    favour=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.favbutton);

    Station station = getItem(position);

    convertView.setTag(station);

    title.setText(station.title);
    icon.setIcon(station.thumb);
    description.setText(station.description);

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: Just get the view returned and get the child view according to the id or the type, than read the text from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
        {
            Value That u Pass In Adapter
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


  inside the getview methed also see Toast 

    title.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

        }
    });
    icon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

        }
    });
    favour.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

        }
    });
```

Comment: i want the position of the button in listview on onclick of button.

Comment: we re geting single row in list view if u want to position of textview than fire setonclick listner on getview methed of adapter

Answer (score 0):

You can use your list widgets in getView method in your custom adapter as follows-

```
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View gridView = convertView;
        if (gridView == null) {
            gridView = mInflater.inflate(layoutId, null);
        }


        TextView tv1 = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        Button button = (Button)gridView.findViewById(R.id.btn);
}
```

Now on button click, you can use text views.

Comment: Can you please explain it little more . From above code how can i get the textview data ? All i want is the data of both textview while i click on the button .

Comment: tv1.getText().toString();

Answer (score 0):

just set an `onclick listener` in your `getView` method;

```
    icon = (IconView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.station_icon);
    title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.station_title);
    description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.station_description);
    favour=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.favbutton);
```

then inside your `onclick listener` get the `TextView's` text.

```
favour.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
       //title.getText() 
       // description.getText();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

//Here I have one textview and edit text and submit button in list view

@Override

public View getView (int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
                {

```
                final View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                final TextView txt= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblMenuname);
                final EditText QtyView = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                Button b=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnInterview);
                b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String txt2 = txt.getText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(ItemList.this,txt2.toString() + "=" + QtyView.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                return v;
            }
```